# When using title case, how should hyphenated words be capitalized?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, titles, headline-case, camel-case

Here's one title that includes a hyphenated words. Also this includes a word that is sometimes capitalized in title case.

> Aliens are coming in the not-too-distant future!

Or an article called:

> AIP-040 Non-Fungible Token Standard

Is it the responsibility of the style guide to fully specific how title case works? If so, this question is for naught.

But if title case actually has some universal meaning then how do we apply that meaning to hyphenated words?

Comment: “Aliens are coming soon” sounds better and avoids the problem. “The Alien Invasion is imminent!” even better. Matter of taste whether to capitalize imminent.

Comment: Less contrived example added

Answer (score 3):

The [Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org)'s guidelines for hyphenated words in titles:

Capitalize the first element of the hyphenated word.

Capitalize
   subsequent elements unless they are articles, prepositions, or
   coordinating conjunctions (and, but, for, or, nor): High-Quality Web 
   Services First-Rate U.S. Lawyers Bed-and-Breakfast Options in
   Savannah

Capitalize the second element in a hyphenated spelled-out
   number. Forty-Ninth Street Blues  Do not capitalize the second
   element if the first element is a prefix that could not stand alone by itself
   (such as anti- or pre-). Anti-inflammatory Dieting

Comment: Words Into Type, Third Edition (Englewood Cliffs, NJ: Prentice-Hall, 1974). It's undoubtedly out of print but there must be copies available. Even the obsolete parts about typesetting are very informative, and the sections on editing and page makeup are well written with lucid examples. It also has some great lists, such as which prepositions go with which words.

Answer (score 2):

In a title, capitalize both parts of a temporary compound, says *Words Into Type*, a temporary compound being words that are not normally joined by a hyphen. An example it gives: "Well-Known Authors." The words *well* and *known* are joined by a hyphen only when they form a compound modifier, so they are a temporary compound. A permanent compound would be a word that is always hyphenated. *Words Into Type* gives the example *son-in-law* and says that in a title, only the first part of the word (*son*) would be capitalized.

Comment: Can you give a reference for "Words into Type"? Even if it’s a link to buy it on Amazon?